# Using Javascript to load X3D models

Tags: javascript, java, x3d

I know this might seem like a silly question, but I'm making a project that loads different X3D models and displays them in Java, I know how to load Javascript files into Java.

My question is, is how would I go about loading the X3D models into Javascript? I'm going to carry on looking online to see if I can find a way to do it and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use: [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/).
With X3DOM you'll be able to dinamically import your X3D file into the webpage's DOM by using JavaScript, and displaying it without the use of any specific X3D-plugin.
The X3D --> X3DOM node mapping process hasn't been completed yet, so some of your X3D nodes could not work as expected when integrated into the webpage with X3DOM. For more information about the currently supported X3D nodes in X3DOM take a look at the following document: [X3dNodeInventoryComparison](http://www.web3d.org/specifications/X3dNodeInventoryComparison.pdf).